# Action class not working using RemoteWebdriver

Tags: java, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I have developed a testing framework using cucumber and I'm using the Actions class in WebDriver to carry out some mouse move and click operations and when i run my framework locally on eclipse (Runas->Junit), it works as expected and for the same i have also created a job in jenkins and when i run my job, this functionality doesn't work as expected. It throws error "openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException"

Below is my code:-

```
@FindBy(how = How.CSS, using = ".poster>img")
    public static WebElement image;

public void Trailor() throws InterruptedException{
        Actions action=new Actions(driver);
        action.moveToElement(image).perform();
        Thread.sleep(2000);

Jenkins Exception:-

   T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Feature: Test PVRCinemas.com NOW SHOWING Functionality
Running Scenario: NOW SHOWING Flow

Sep 13, 2016 12:04:02 PM org.bridj.BridJ log
INFO: Registering type org.sikuli.util.SysJNA$WinKernel32
Sep 13, 2016 12:04:02 PM org.bridj.BridJ log
INFO: Registering type org.bridj.TimeT
Sep 13, 2016 12:04:03 PM org.bridj.BridJ log
INFO: Registering type org.bridj.TimeT$timeval_customizer
Sep 13, 2016 12:04:03 PM org.bridj.BridJ log
INFO: Registering type org.bridj.StructIO$DefaultCustomizer
Sep 13, 2016 12:04:03 PM org.bridj.BridJ log
INFO: Registering type org.bridj.TimeT$timeval
Sep 13, 2016 12:04:03 PM org.bridj.BridJ log
INFO: Registering type org.bridj.StructObject
Sep 13, 2016 12:04:03 PM org.bridj.BridJ log
INFO: Registering type org.bridj.NativeObject
Sep 13, 2016 12:04:03 PM org.bridj.BridJ log
INFO: Registering type org.bridj.AbstractIntegral
Sep 13, 2016 12:04:03 PM org.bridj.BridJ log
INFO: Registering type java.lang.Number
[error] Location: outside any screen (26136544, 0) - subsequent actions might not work as expected
[error] Location: outside any screen (26136768, 0) - subsequent actions might not work as expected

[error] Location: outside any screen (26136768, 0) - subsequent actions might not work as expected
[error] Location: outside any screen (26136384, 0) - subsequent actions might not work as expected
[error] RobotDesktop: checkMousePosition: should be L(26136768,0)
but after move is L(26136384,0)
Possible cause in case you did not touch the mouse while script was running:
 Mouse actions are blocked generally or by the frontmost application.
You might try to run the SikuliX stuff as admin.

share location browser pop up not found

click on Now Showing tab

  Background:                                          [90m# J_NowShowing.feature:3[0m
    [32mWhen [0m[32mNavigate to PVRCinemas.com and share location[0m [90m# Cinemas.navigate_to_PVRCinemas_com_and_share_location()[0m
    [32mThen [0m[32mclick on Now Showing tab[0m                      [90m# NowShowing.click_on_Now_Showing_tab()[0m

Get all the movie count of movies which are visible
prior displayed false
prior enabled true

after displayed false
after enabled true

Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 149.629 sec <<< FAILURE! - in Scenario: NOW SHOWING Flow
Then Click on Trailor of movie(Scenario: NOW SHOWING Flow)  Time elapsed: 0.043 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: 
Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 20.15 seconds
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
System info: host: 'HT', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.7.0_55'
Session ID: 3c8dbc9c-514d-4da8-8616-bd61431b6fbb
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=44.0.2}]
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: 
Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
System info: host: 'HT', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.7.0_55'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Running Scenario: NOW SHOWING Flow
[34mCurrent Page URL is http://www.pvrcinemas.com/[0m

  Scenario: NOW SHOWING Flow                                  [90m# J_NowShowing.feature:7[0m
    [32mGiven [0m[32mGet all the movie count of movies which are visible[0m [90m# NowShowing.get_all_the_movie_count_of_movies_which_are_visible()[0m
    [31mThen [0m[31mClick on Trailor of movie[0m                            [90m# NowShowing.click_on_Trailor_of_movie()[0m
      [31morg.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
      Command duration or timeout: 20.15 seconds
      Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
      System info: host: 'HT', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.7.0_55'
      Session ID: 3c8dbc9c-514d-4da8-8616-bd61431b6fbb
      Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
      Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=44.0.2}]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:327)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:85)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:51)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.click(Unknown Source)
        at pageObject.NowShowingPage.Trailor(NowShowingPage.java:100)
        at stepdefinitions.NowShowing.click_on_Trailor_of_movie(NowShowing.java:35)
        at ?.Then Click on Trailor of movie(J_NowShowing.feature:9)
      Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
      Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
      System info: host: 'HT', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.7.0_55'
      Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Please help,i have also tried implicit and explicit waits but the same doesn't work by running jenkins job, throws same above exception.

Comment: Please check whether the element is hidden or not

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the object isn’t visible and there fore can’t be interacted with.

It is unfortunately hard to say why. I would start my trouble shooting by running the test as the same user Jenkins runs as on tat host. Maybe there is something obvious when you do that.